# ReSharper: formatting of delegates

Tags: resharper

I like my code formatted like this:

```
WithDataContext.Execute(
    delegate(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        // code goes here.
    });
```

ReSharper wants to auto-format it like this:

```
WithDataContext.Execute(
                           delegate(DataContext dataContext)
                               {
                                   // code goes here.
                               });
```

What options do I need to tweak to get what I want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ReSharper -> Options -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Braces Layout -> Anonymous method declaration

Set to "At next line (BSD style)"

ReSharper -> Options -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Other -> Align Multiline Constructs

Uncheck "Call Arguments" and you'll get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an option to format quite like that that I can find, but take a look at ReSharper|Options: Languages|C#|Formatting Style|Braces Layout. It has a number of options like anonymous type format.

Comment: By setting "Anonymous Method Declaration", I can get the delegate to line up properly. Good. Where are the extra spaces coming from at the start of the 'delegate' line?